# Tracing ETW during NUnit runs

Tags: c#, multithreading, nunit, resharper, etw

I'm working on a multithreaded application and I know there's some kind of race condition/deadlock in my application because every once in a while, one of my unit tests get stuck and never finish (for now I've remedied this using the NUnit Timeout attribute). I can never replicate this when I'm debugging the test.

I have ETW tracing already coded into my application, which would definitely help in debugging this issue. The problem is that to do ETW tracing, the application must be started by PerfView or another application that shares memory with the application under trace (as far as I know).

My question is: Does anyone know of a way to run an NUnit test and have the ETW trace events be logged in a separate file that can be run through PerfView later? This way whenever I see my test fail, I can look at the trace from that run and analyze to see what is going on. As a side note, I'm using Resharper's NUnit runner.

Any other approaches/techniques are welcome. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Perfview already logs the data into an ETL file

Comment: Yes it does, but it needs to be done in a single process - you run the application using PerfView and it logs the data. I would like to have the data be logged during running of the test using NUnit and look at the data later using PerfView.

Comment: The application does not need to be run by perfview. ETW data is collected machine wide not per application. You could setup a collector via perfmon or logman on the test machine and then analyze it with perfview later.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any tutorials to setup the collector part using perfmon? I will look for ways to do this.

Comment: you can capture your own events via xperf or via WPR if you create your own profile (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448223.aspx), but this is ugly as hell.

Answer (score 1):

- Write a simple implementation derived from
  [EventListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener(v=vs.110).aspx) that
  collects ETW traces for providers you interested to listen.
- Dump the
  content of stored traces to a file manually or use some library (for example you could just serialize the collection of logs into a JSON string and write it to a text file) or even validate the stored events as a part of test validation.
- Update your tests to use that listener.

In this case you could have that file with traces created event on a build controller machine where you might not have permissions/access to use logman/PerfMon.